# Alien romance novel. A girl is paired off with a male as part of a space programme

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read this alien romance book about 1-2 years ago I think.

It’s about a girl who willingly goes into space as part of a programme where she’s paired with a male. She goes back to his house and then some of the food she sees looks similar to Earth food but different colours and slightly different flavour

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover art?  Was it set on a spaceship or alien planet?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.